# get string value from UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, iphone, uisegmentedcontrol

How can I get the text value of a segment in a UISegmentedControl?

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Objective-C

```
NSString *title = [segment titleForSegmentAtIndex:segment.selectedSegmentIndex];
```

Swift:

```
let title = segment.titleForSegment(at: segment.selectedSegmentIndex)
```

Answer (score 31):

```
[segmentedControl titleForSegmentAtIndex:int];
```

For the current selected index

```
[segmentedControl titleForSegmentAtIndex:[segmentedControl selectedSegmentIndex]];
```

Answer (score 5):

Swift 3:

```
segmentedControl.titleForSegment(at: segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
```

Comment: wondering why is this call giving me `extra argument 'at' in call` error in swift 3 with Xcode 8.3

Answer (score 3):

As this is the first Google result and we are now in the swift era:

Swift:

```
seg_ctrl.titleForSegmentAtIndex( seg_ctrl.selectedSegmentIndex)
```